# Blender cutting face to fit a hole

Tags: knife-tool

I have a hole like this in my mesh

[image: 1]

I wish to fill these 2 holes by cutting larger faces to fit, that way I don't have to do the UVs myself since these large square faces already have UVs. Example:

[image: 2]

What is the easiest way to cut these 3 faces to fit the hole? I've tried the knife tool but it's not really working out, it does not snap to the points behind and sometimes, it doesn't even cut the faces.

Comment: Have you tried the knife tool? By default K key under edit mode

Comment: I already mentioned that the knife tool doesn't really work

Comment: You could select the top vertex and press `G` + `G` to initiate vertex slide, it wont distort UVs, though you wont be able to snap that way, but if they are halfway distance you could input `0.5`instead.

Comment: Works well for me since I use increment snapping for this project, so all my vertex are following a set grid, thanks. If you repost it as an answer, I'll accept it and close the question thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the top vertex and press <kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>G</kbd> to initiate vertex slide

It will move the vertex along the edges they belong to without distorting UVs.

You wont be able to snap that way though, but your model seems to be using some sort of grid metric so if they are halfway distance you could input `0.5` instead.

Comment: For future readers, note that if you're going from a 4 vertex face to fill a 3 vertex hole like here, you can simply select the faces after filling the hole then "Remove Doubles" (w > Remove Doubles)